# PHP Not Parsing, Blank Webpage

Tags: php, xampp

After installing XAMPP on windows, I am able to access the XAMPP site through `http://localhost/xampp/` just fine but when I try to access a .php file I place in c:\xampp\htdocs I get a blank page.

Here is my PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?>  

</body>
</html>
```

If the XAMPP homepage uses PHP than that means PHP, Apache and MySQL have installed correctly. Why are my .php files not being parsed?

Comment: Go to http://localhost/filename.php

Answer (score 0):

instead of `localhost/xampp/` try to access  `localhost/yourfile.php` and let us know if it shows any error